# OpenCV error: "(-217:Gpu API call) unknown error in function 'getCudaEnabledDeviceCount'"

Tags: python, opencv

I got these error when I'm trying to verify my GPUs:

```
import cv2<br/>
cv2.__version__<br/>
4.7.0'<br/>
 count = cv2.cuda.getCudaEnabledDeviceCount()<br/>
Traceback (most recent call last):<br/>
  File "stdin", line 1, in module> <br/>
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) /home/*****/opencv-4.7.0/modules/core/src/cuda_info.cpp:62: error: (-217:Gpu API call) unknown error in function 'getCudaEnabledDeviceCount'
```

NVIDIA-SMI 510.85.03    Driver Version: 510.85.03    CUDA Version: 12.0

```
    Compiling OpenCV returns no errors.


Edit for more informations:
Host is Proxmox (Linux 5.15.83-1-pve #1 SMP PVE 5.15.83-1) and the gpu is passed through a LXC.

nvidia-smi of the proxmox host:



nvidia-smi of the LXC:


    Compiling options:

-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
-D WITH_CUDA=ON \
-D WITH_CUDNN=ON \
-D OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON \
-D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 \
-D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 \
-D CUDA_ARCH_BIN=6.1 \
-D WITH_CUBLAS=1 \
-D BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules \
-D HAVE_opencv_python3=ON \
-D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 \
-D PYTHON2_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python2 \
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON 


nvcc -V of the LXC:

    nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Oct_24_19:12:58_PDT_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.0, V12.0.76
Build cuda_12.0.r12.0/compiler.31968024_0
```

Comment: You're missing double periods at the end  `-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..`

Comment: sorry they are there but im confused about the tag settings here. I will edit my post.